# Unable to select database when using SQL Database Migration Wizard v3.9.12 & v4.0.15

Tags: sql, azure

I'm trying to migrate my database table along with my data from SQL server 2008 to SQL azure. After much research, most of the users will give a thumbs up for this program called 
SQL Database Migration Wizard v3.9.12 & v4.0.15. I downloaded it, however, i wasn't able to select the database as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Never used it, but does it matter whether your source database is attached or not? What about current connections? Maybe the migration won't begin while connections remain.

Comment: I have already stop all connection and take my database offline from SQL server.

Comment: George says [link](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/discussions/231235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALWAYS** run such program as administrator. Despite having administrative rights to your computer, at times window doesn't run your program as administrator automatically.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure Migration Wizard 3.* requires SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP1.
SQL Azure Migration Wizard 4.* requires SQL Server 2012.

You can migrate older databases (2005 for instance), but you will need an appropriate version of SQL Server on the machine running the migration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I somehow managed to find out why i cant select my database.